# C# Split text into Substrings

Tags: c#, string, split

What I'm actually trying is to split a StreamReader.ReadLine() object such as "1 A & B 2 C & D" into "1", "A & B", "2" and "C & D" substrings. Anybody an idea of a simple algorithm to implement this splitting?

Comment: Do you mean a string where substrings are separated by numbers or is there a specific format for the strings you will be reading?

Comment: I mean substrings separated by a specific Format [Numbers] [string][numbers][string].

Comment: Hi, maybe check out how to ask a question or post the code you have tried already.
My only suggestion would be to use replace to replace a string with a particular character, maybe like ■ then use split().

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (using a tiny bit of Linq): ?

```
    static private List<string> Parse(string s)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        string[] rawTextParts = s.Split(new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' });
        var textParts = rawTextParts.Where(t => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t)).Select(t => t.Trim());
        foreach (string textPart in textParts)
        {
            string numberstring = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(textPart)).Trim();
            s = s.Substring(s.IndexOf(textPart) + textPart.Length);
            result.Add(numberstring);
            result.Add(textPart);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Nice idea with splitting the string by possible digits! However, there might be some corner cases if we should support arbitrary integers.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is made for pattern matching. There are two patterns, Alphabetic character(s) a non character and alphabetic character(s) or the final pattern of numbers. Here is the regex to do such:

```
var input = "1 A & B 2 C & D";
var pattern = @"[a-zA-Z]\s+\W\s+[a-zA-Z]|\d+";

var resultItems  =
Regex.Matches(input, pattern)
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select(m => m.Value)
     .ToList();
```

Result is

[image]

---

The `\s+` was not mentioned for that handles all spaces, such it is 1 to many spaces for something like (`A   &    B`). If you believe there will be no spaces such `A&B` use `\s*` which is zero to many spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to infer precise requirements from your question. But according to your example I'd come with something like:

```
void Main()
{
    var input = "1 A & B 2 C & D";  
    var result = Parse(input);
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", result));
}

static IEnumerable<string> Parse(string input)
{
    var words = input.Split();  
    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(word, out var value))
        {
            if (builder.Length > 0)
            {
                yield return builder.ToString();
                builder.Clear();
            }
            yield return word;
        }
        else 
        {
            if (builder.Length > 0)
            {           
                builder.Append(' ');
            }
            builder.Append(word);
        }
    }

    if (builder.Length > 0) // leftovers
    {
        yield return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

The output of the above code will be:

```
1
A & B
2
C & D
```